# Java - Warn about resource leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks

How would i warn someone adding to my code that a method must be called at the end of usage to stop resources from being leaked. BufferedReader is an example of this, when using it notifies you that the reader.close() must be called. How would i do this within my own code. object.close() must be called.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(..);

br.readLine();
```

br will recieve the following warning - Resource leak: 'br' is never closed

This is what i would like to repeat.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: So people are aware i do know that br.close() has to be called. I want to be able to repeat this with my own class so that myclass.close() has to be called or the resource warning will be given.

Comment: Is this eclipse(or your IDE) warning by any chance?

Comment: oh... that is probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the compiler warnings - but implementing `Closeable` yourself might be a good idea - that way you both signal to your users "there's something to close here" *and* allow for try-with-resource handling yourself.

Check [eclipse compiler settings](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm&anchor=resource-leak)

Comment: Ok. I assume the compiler warnings are created for the specific methods for those and are therefore non-repeatable. I will implement Closeable and  just leave it at that. Thanks

Comment: Check the link I added - and maybe upvote all helpful answers... :-)

Comment: I did this and it worked! Thanks. I never knew about the eclipse compiler documents. I will be sure to refer to that if another problem like this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm):

> Classes implementing the interface java.io.Closeable (since JDK 1.5) and java.lang.AutoCloseable (since JDK 1.7) are considered to represent external resources, which should be closed using method close(), when they are no longer needed.

So, make your custom classes implement one of those interfaces.

Comment: I tried this, the same warning is not repeated but i will look further. Thanks